# Rest input in each div with id++

Tags: jquery, html, reset

I created a script which unfortunately works individually, I have a form that at the click generates a div with the form fields filled in, I added the "Reset button in each generated form," only that each form has a generated id .

How can I give an id + 1 (or similar button)

```
// RESET 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.variation').find('input:text').val('');
});
//Function
function resetAllValues() {
        $('.variation').find('input:text').val('');
}
```

Div 1:

```
    <div class="variation section-variation0"><input type="button" value="Delete variation" onclick="resetAllValues();">
<label>Field1:</label> <input type="text" name="variations0"  id="variations0" value=""> 
</div>
```

Div 2

```
    <div class="variation section-variation1"><input type="button" value="Delete  variation" onclick="resetAllValues();">
<label>Field1:</label> <input type="text" name="variations1"  id="variations1" value=""> 
</div>
```

Etc.
I hope I was clear enough, thanks to all for the help.

EDIT
I have a code for generate a new div with each click on the button, the new divs has class like "section-variation0", "section-variation1" etc.

With the first script I generate also a RESET button for the input inside, so i need a RESET for each div, "section-variation0", "section-variation1" etc.

At moment my button reset all the divs and not also section-variation0 or section-variation1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED - From what I gather, this should do the trick.  Of note, I have removed your inline function call and moved it into jquery.  Also, I have added a class to your buttons "variationClass" so that every time the button is pressed it can be referenced by that.  When clicked, the function will look for it's sibling element "input" and fill it with an empty string.  I would encourage however that if your divs will eventually have multiple input elements, then add a class to each and then use this function to change the values of that input class specifically.  I hope this is the solution you are looking for!

```js
$(".variationButton").on("click", function resetAllValues() {
  var inputField = $(this).siblings('input');
  inputField.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="variation section-variation1"><input type="button" class="variationButton" value="Delete variation">
<label>Field1:</label> <input type="text" name="variations1"  id="variations1" value=""> 
</div>

<div class="variation section-variation0"><input type="button" class="variationButton" value="Delete variation">
<label>Field2:</label> <input type="text" name="variations0"  id="variations0" value=""> 
</div>
```

Comment: I had already a div generation, I just want to add the button in each divs, but with my code the button reset all the forms in all the div

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you please post more of your code or give me a detailed explanation of what needs to happen?

Comment: Solved ^^ @Fuel89